# AngularJS: Is it bad to add ng-form to each and every form field?

Tags: angularjs

I'm thinking of adding an ng-form to every single one of my form fields, so that I can use css instead of ng-show to show/hide field errors (to reduce watchers). Are there any serious downsides that I need to be aware of?

For e.g. I want to convert the following:

```
<div id="fld_field1" class="form-group">
    <label for="field1" class="control-label col-xs-6">Field 1</label>
    <div class="control-wrapper col-xs-6">
        <input  class="form-control"  ng-required="true" name="field1"  type="text" ng-model="fm.data.field1" id="field1"/>
        <small class="hints">
            <div class="error" ng-show="fm.field1.$error.required && fm.field1.$dirty">Field is required.</div>
            <div class="error" ng-show="!fm.field1.$valid && !fm.field1.$error.required && fm.field1.$dirty">Field is invalid.</div>
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

To this:

(html)

```
<div ng-form id="fld_field1" class="form-group">
    <label for="field1" class="control-label col-xs-6">Field 1</label>
    <div class="control-wrapper col-xs-6">
        <input  class="form-control"  ng-required="true" name="field1"  type="text" ng-model="fm.data.field1" id="field1"/>
        <small class="hints">
            <div class="error error-required">Field is required.</div>
            <div class="error error-invalid">Field is invalid.</div>
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

(css)

```
.hints .error { display: none; }
.form-group.ng-invalid.ng-dirty .error-invalid { display: block; }
.form-group.ng-invalid-required.ng-dirty .error-required { display: block; }
```

Comment: why can't you just add `ng-form` to the parent div?

Comment: that being said, the purpose of `ng-form` is to group controls together, so that the validity of the entire group can be determined.  You would generally want only as many `ng-form` as you have sub-groups on a form.  Treating every control as it's own group isn't necessarily *wrong*, but it's not logically within the purpose declaration of `ng-form`.

Comment: @Claies As I've stated my ultimate purpose is to reduce watchers by removing all the different ng-shows needed per form field to show/hide validation errors. Whether by replacing these watchers with a bunch of ng-form's would result in a net gain or loss in performance is what I'm trying to explore here.

Comment: if you put `ng-form` on the parent element, you don't actually need it on the individual controls in order to access the validation errors.

Comment: @Claies By "parent element" do you mean a parent group/fieldset element that consists of multiple fields? If so how do I control validation errors for each field independent to every other fields in the same group?

Comment: `ng-form` is not free, but it is cheaper than adding a watcher. If you need to group controls, as @Claies suggest, you are free to add more `ng-form`s.